# archiving hidden directories with tar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar, hidden-files

`tar` on a directory `mydir` will archive hidden files and hidden subdirectories, but tar from *within* `mydir` with a `*` wildcard will not.  Is this a known inconsistency or bug?

Edit: Additional information. `tar` from *within* `mydir` with a `*` wildcard will not "see" nor archive hidden files and hidden subdirectories in the *immediate* directory.  However, in the non-hidden subdirectories of `mydir` hidden files and hidden subdirectories will be archived. In other words, deeper in the directory tree the hidden objects will be archived.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is that the `*` wildcard is handled by the shell and it just does not expand to things that start with a dot.  The other wildcard `?` also does not expand to things that start with a dot.  Thanks to Keith for pointing out it is the shell that does the expansion and so it has nothing to do with `tar`.

If you use `shopt -s dotglob` then expansion will include things like `.filename`.  Thanks to Andy.

Use `shopt -u dotglob` to turn it off.

Switching the `dotglob` option does not change `ls` itself.  Rather it just changes expansion behaviour as exhibited in something like `ls *`.

Edit: My recommendations are in a comment below.

Comment: That's interesting but could you show it in an example command?

Comment: @felwithe By using `shopt -s dotglob`, one could easily do something like `tar -cvpzf final.tar.gz *` inside of the directory whose content you wanna to tar

Comment: @felwithe I did not show an example because I decided non-obvious behaviour happens when you tar with the * wildcard. I also think that changing the default behaviour with shopt is suboptimal. That is, avoid the non-obvious and avoid non-defaults. I decided it is better to explicitly name what you want to tar, if at all possible.

Answer (score 45):

With wildcard it will not work. You have to specify . (current directory) if you mean full directory including hidden files. You can do

```
tar -cvpzf test.tgz .
```

Comment: But be careful of placing the new tar inside the same directory you are tarring. You can get into a nasty loop.

Comment: tar cvpfz test.tgz --exclude=*.tgz .

Comment: Or just put it somewhere else: `tar czpf /var/tmp/mytar.tgz .`.

Comment: Putting it somewhere else might mean using sudo which might cause additional work (which you might want to avoid) in dealing with the GUI-based scheduler or crontab.

Comment: But you can always write to /var/tmp. That's how I usually do it, in fact.

Comment: I wrote the solution `tar cvpfz test.tgz --exclude=*.tgz .` in a comment above because it solves the problem of not wanting to tar the new tar file but I do not recommend it. I think it's better to invoke tar from outside (that is from the parent directory) so you explicitly name the directory to tar and avoid the `.` (dot). That has the benefit of being explicit and the benefit that you avoid needing the `--exclude` option.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
tar -cvpzf test.tgz * .??*
```

But, this works only for hidden files with names > 2 (to prevent '.' and '..')

Answer (score 4):

You can compress all the files / folders in your current directory (including .hidden) by using:

```
tar -zcvf compressed.tgz `ls -A -1`
```

The last argument are the folders you want to compress. If you pass it `ls -A -1` , you are passing it all folders in your current directory but `.` and `..` . 
When it comes to subdirectories, .hidden files are already included in the compression by default.

Comment: This command doesn't work if you have in the directory files with space in the name

Answer (score 2):

The shell expands the wildcards so tar doesn't even see it. You have to add them explicitly if you want to do that. (`.*`). However, it's most common to tar a single directory so that when you untar it all goes to the same place.

Comment: Actually tar on .* will go up (probably as high as the root) so you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Correction: not as high as the root.

Comment: Oh right. It would be safer to use something like `.[a-zA-Z]*`. But, I always prefer to just tar one directory (parent, if need be).

Comment: This comment discusses both tar and the ls (list) command which is hard to see in this font.  The shell might be responsible for expanding the * wildcard.  However, for the . wildcard tar and ls behave differently so I don't know if the shell is providing a consistent behaviour in the case of the dot.  ls . ignores hidden stuff (not consistent with tar) and ls -a . can see the .. (above) directory which is also not consistent with what tar will archive.  tar only goes down with a . unless you do .* which we already discussed.

Comment: The dot(.) is not a wildcard in shell globbing. It is the name of the current directory. Old systems even had a physical directory entry of `.`.  It is therefore consistent since the shell doesn't expand it.

Comment: However, to confuse things further, if you're using bash shell you can set the `dotglob` option (shopt -s dotglob) to disable the special handling of names starting with dot.

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

this will make the

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you forgot do finish your message?

Comment: Keith explains this answer in one of his comments.

Answer (score -2):

This will tar all hidden files and directories

```
tar -cvzf hidden.tgz `ls -a | egrep [.][^.]+`
```