# Tar Directory Contents Without Creating A Root Folder In Archive

Tags: bash, tar, hidden-files

I am running the following snippet in a bash script in a folder. This creates an archive where there is no root folder since I am running the script within the folder whose contents I am archiving.

```
tar -pczf $ARCHIVE_NAME --exclude=${ARCHIVE_NAME} --exclude=$(basename ${0}) *

Archive Contents:
/a/
/b/
/c/
/a_normal_file
```

works great, but since I am using the * it is not archiving hidden files in the immediate directory. I did some searching and found [archiving (ubuntu tar) hidden directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572973/archiving-ubuntu-tar-hidden-directories) I have then changed it to:

```
tar -pczf $ARCHIVE_NAME --exclude=${ARCHIVE_NAME} --exclude=$(basename ${0}) .

Archive Contents:
/./a/
/./b/
/./c/
/./.a_hidden_file
/./a_normal_file
```

still works, but now there is a root folder being created with the name being the '.' character. The contents are then within that. How do I get my previous result, but where it still archives hidden files in the immediate directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't affect the unpacking of the archive (since `.` just refers to the same dir), if it bothers you, you can change the wildcard from `*` to `.[^.]* *` to include all the hidden files as well.

In addition, if you have hidden files beginning with `..`, such as `..a`, you'll need to add `..?*` to the list as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use -C, --directory DIR

```
--directory=$(dirname ${0})
```

Example:

```
$ ls -a xxx
.  ..  aaa  .bbb
$ tar cvf test.tar --exclude test.tar -C xxx .
./
./.bbb
./aaa
```

Comment: some explanation will help this answer

Comment: I edited the answer adding an example. "-C" parameter changes the current working directory before listing files to archive (so the files have relative paths). "$(dirname ${0})" is a directory in which the script was run (I think author wanted to archive files inside that directory).